# How do I pass a New line character to JavaScript from my Servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, newline

I'm setting the following in the request attribute:

```
confirmMsg = "REf No: \n 112"; 
req.setAttribute("confirmMsg", confirmMsg);
```

I need the above to be displayed like(in alert box) :

Ref No:

112

I'm using the following onload function in my JavaScript to show the message on loading the page.

```
function onLoad() {
 var msg = "${confirmMsg}";
  if(msg != null && msg != "") {
    alert(msg);
   }

}
```

The above throws a script error? How do I pass the newline character?

Comment: Please do not confuse JSP and JavaScript. There is nothing at all in common in the meaning of those words.

Comment: What is the "script error" that you are receiving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\n` needs to be JavaScript-escaped to be put in a JavaScript string literal.

Use commons-lang `StringEscapeUtils.escapeECMAScript()` to eascape the message, and pass this escaped message to your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, do not confuse JSP with JavaScript.

What you want to do is output a string message from your JSP/Servlet (JSP is a Servlet) to be used in a JavaScript code block.

To do this your message needs to be encoded for JavaScript, such as using the StringEscapeUtils.escapeECMAScript method described by JB Nizet.

Then you need, in your jsp or servlet creating the response, to output the variable where you want it for the javascript to act upon, for this you do

```
<%= confirmMsg %>
```

and not ${} as that is an expression language which is not always available in every jsp.

In short, change from "${confirmMsg}" to <%= confirmMsg %> or <%= (String)request.getParameter("confirmMsg") %> // or request.getAttribute and so on

Comment: The JSP EL has been introduced yeaaaars ago. Scriptlets are something from the past which should not be used anymore for years and years.